# Jenkins Kubernetes container $WORKSPACE environement variable not consistent

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using a declarative pipeline with a Kubernetes setup with two Containers per agent pod.
One of them is the basic Jenkins agent, the other is a Python container on which I want to execute my test suite. The two containers have different workspace directories.

To keep my shell block as clean as possible and since I want to use the credentials helper, I'm using an `environment` block to assign the environment variables for my testing stage. Through trial and error I have found out that it doesn't seem to be possible to execute an `environment` block in a specific container, since the `container` block is only allowed inside of `steps`.

My workaround for this is to assign my Python container as the `defaultContainer` as this makes sure that the `environment` block is also executed on the Python container. By the way, if you have a better solution for this, please share it!

My problem lies in assigning my `PYTHONPATH`. Since my project relies on multiple directories to be part of `PYTHONPATH`, I've been assigning it as follows:

```
environment{
  PYTHONPATH = "$WORKSPACE/dir1:$WORKSPACE/dir2"
}
```

When I check the value of `PYTHONPATH`, I get the following:

```
+ echo $PYTHONPATH
WORKING_DIR_OF_PYTHON_CONTAINER/dir1:WORKING_DIR_OF_AGENT_CONTAINER/dir2
```

Any idea on how this could happen? My understanding was that the entire `environment` block is executed on the `defaultContainer` (in this case the Python container) meaning that `WORKSPACE` should consistently match the working directory of that container. Clearly this is not the case.

I have found that I can work around this by assigning `PYTHONPATH` inside my shell block:

```
steps {
  sh '''
    export PYTHONPATH="$WORKSPACE/dir1:$WORKSPACE/dir2"
  '''
}
```

Checking `PYTHONPATH` then yields the following:

```
+ echo $PYTHONPATH
WORKING_DIR_OF_PYTHON_CONTAINER/dir1:WORKING_DIR_OF_PYTHON_CONTAINER/dir2
```

Is there any way of making this work without assigning the environment variable inside of the shell block?

Full Jenkinsfile below:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        kubernetes {
            yaml '''
                apiVersion: v1
                kind: Pod
                spec:
                containers:
                - name: jnlp
                    image: MY_AGENT_IMAGE
                    resources:
                    limits:
                        memory: 1Gi
                    requests:
                        memory: 1Gi
                    workingDir: WORKING_DIR_OF_AGENT_CONTAINER
                - name: python
                    image: MY_PYTHON_IMAGE
                    resources:
                    limits:
                        memory: 1Gi
                    requests:
                        memory: 1Gi
                    workingDir: WORKING_DIR_OF_PYTHON_CONTAINER
                    command:
                    - cat
                    tty: true
                label: jenkins
                name: jenkins-agent
                namespace: MY_NAMESPACE
                serviceAccountName: jenkins
            '''
            defaultContainer 'python'
            workspaceVolume persistentVolumeClaimWorkspaceVolume(claimName: 'jenkins', readOnly: false)
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Execute unit tests') {
            environment{
                PYTHONPATH = "$WORKSPACE/dir1:$WORKSPACE/dir2"
            }
            steps {
                sh '''
                    echo $PYTHONPATH
                '''
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `withEnv` [step](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#withenv-set-environment-variables):

```
            steps {
                withEnv(["PYTHONPATH=$WORKSPACE/dir1:$WORKSPACE/dir2"]) {
                    sh '''
                        echo $PYTHONPATH
                    '''
                }
            }
```

But to answer your question - no I have no idea why `WORKSPACE` variable is inconsistent and it *is* weird.